# Is radix sort in-place or out-place?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, python, in-place

Generally, we can implement algorithms in-place and out-of-place.

However, I can't say for certain that radix sort can be implemented in both ways.

Comment: What prevents you from checking that?

Comment: @Dmitry well, it does not return a new array, but it does stores some variables. So I got my answer, 'it depends' (see Nathaniel's answer below)

Comment: Analyzing a piece of Python code is out-of-scope for this site. Coding and implementation-specific questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @D.W. See my edit.

Comment: You should check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#In-place_MSD_radix_sort_implementations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the definition of in-place algorithm you are using.

- if in-place just means that the algorithm transforms the input without returning a new array, then yes;
- if you also want to use no additionnal data structure, or limit the additionnal space usage to be $o(n)$, then no, because of the creation of the arrays `count` and `output`.

There are different meanings to an in-place algorithm, as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).

Comment: can we implement radix sorting algorithm without using additional space?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.